# Difference between "al detalle" and "en detalle"?

Tags: diferencias-entre-palabras

Would it be more correct to say, "el contenido está al detalle" o "el contenido está en detalle"?

The context is:

> Todo el contenido médico se trata al detalle y está completamente al día, por descontado.

I think "en detalle" also is correct, but which is more correct?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: The context is: "Todo el contenido médico se trata al detalle y está completamente al día, por descontado: " Thanks for your help. I think "en detalle" also is correct, but which is more correct?

Comment: What is the specific English idea you want to get across??

Comment: Todos los detalles del contenido médico están actualizados

Answer (score 1):

Según la RAE (Real Academia Española) en este contexto es correcto utilizar «con detalle», «en detalle» y «al detalle».

Personalmente utilizaría «en detalle».

---

"Al detalle" es una frase que se emplea en comercio para indicar la venta minorista, por lo que puede crear confusión (*retail* in English).

Ejemplo:

- En este comercio mayorista está permitida la venta *al detalle*.

---

La preposición *con* por lo general implica un añadido. Si bien es correcta su utilización en la frase, no se está agregando más contenido que el texto ya detallado. Por lo que –*Todo el contenido médico se trata con detalle*– es correcto y comprensible, pero no es la opción más acertada a mi entender.

Comment: Gracias, Danielillo!

Comment: Pero que quiere decir: todo el contenido medico se trata con detalle?

Comment: Used "en detalle" but thanks

Answer (score 0):

En este caso concreto, la opción que más me encaja es

> Todo el contenido médico se trata **de forma detallada** y está completamente al día, por descontado.